# Is there a liaison in the phrase "est en"?

Tags: liaisons

I know that liaison often happens with article + noun (les amis), adjective + noun (beaux amis), and personal pronoun + verb (ils ont).

But how about the situation of verb + preposition? e.g.

> Kaboul est en Afghanistan.
>
> Bangkok est en Thaïlande.

When speaking the sentences above, would there be a liaison between est and en?

Comment: Liaisons do not "often happen": they **always happen**  (mandatory and always spoken)   "with article + noun (les amis), adjective + noun (beaux amis), and personal pronoun + verb (ils ont)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three sorts of liaisons in French: mandatory, forbidden and optional.<sup>1</sup>

The liaison after *est* is mandatory and always pronounced:

- in the set phrase: *c'est-à-dire* /sɛtadiʁ/
- when the verb is followed by a subject pronoun: *Est-il arrivé* ? /ɛtil/

Other liaisons after *est* are optional but they are more or less followed according to the nature of the word that follows *est*.

Very frequent:

- when *est* is followed by a past participle:

  > *Il est arrivé* /ilɛtaʁive/
- when *est* is followed by an attribute:

  > *C'est une vieille histoire* /sɛtyn/

Just frequent, often omitted in relaxed conversation, in most other cases, including in front of prepositions:

- *Paris est en France* /ɛtɑ̃/ or /ɛɑ̃/
- *Il est à la maison* /ɛta/ or /ɛa/

We note that the French language has been (and probably still is) operating a shift from mandatory to optional liaisons. For example the 10th edition of [*Le Bon Usage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) states that the liaisons between *c'est* and the following preposition, and between *est* and the following past participle are mandatory, but when we listen to people in France in the 21st century (I would not know about other French speaking countries and it might be different) there's a great tendency to drop it in casual speech.

<sup>1</sup> 
 <sub>- A [guide to liaisons in French](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/liaisons/)

 - [Quelques règles de liaisons](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/regles-de-liaison.php)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Both liaisons are optional in your examples.

## Rationale

As regards verbs, liaisons are mandatory in the following case:

> Entre le pronom personnel (ainsi que "on", "en" et "y") et son verbe, ainsi que l'inverse : *nous avons, elles aiment, on ouvre, ont-ils, prends-en, allons-y*.

As well as in "c'est̲-̲à̲-dire".

### References

- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_obligatoire
- My experience as a native speaker.
- [Laure's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/27380/14343)

Comment: Merci. Mais une question plus. Would you say it is more common or not to use a liaison in my examples?

Comment: It's slightly more common not to use it. You won't sound that formal by making these liaisons, and vice-versa.

Comment: Btw my above answer is as true in your instances as it is in general.

Comment: **sole following case** is inaccurate.

Comment: "c'est-à-dire" is indeed an exception to the rule. Is it what you were referring to?